# How do you detect ALT combos in Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, keyboard-shortcuts

We're building an app that makes use of hotkeys, it's a web UI to an existing windows app.
Normally you can check that

```
Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt
```

However when you're using combos with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the browser captures the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keystroke to see if it can handle it.

The only way around this I've seen so far is to manually wire up to the keydown events in the DOM like this:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Body.AttachEvent("onkeydown", new EventHandler<System.Windows.Browser.HtmlEventArgs>(OnBodyKeyDown));
```

Then have your code check signal with a flag whether the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed or not.
This is described [here](https://silverlight.net/forums/t/85402.aspx).

`KeyEventArgs` is sealed so you can't just raise it yourself and you can't set the Modifiers directly.

Clearly this isn't an ideal situation, does anyone have any insight on how this might be better accomplished?

[We're working with Silverlight 3.0.]

Comment: Hi TreeUK

I've just tested this with Silverlight 3.0 on the MouseLeftButtonUp event and Silverlight does detect the alt key.  Can you please post some code that shows the problem?

Comment: Yep, my question is about keyboard combos using Alt not keyboard + mouse.

Comment: I've been searching around and think there really is no better way. There's no PreviewKeyDown in Silverlight either.

Comment: I haven't looked into it, to see if it's changed in v4.0. Have you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this as of v3.0.